# Most efficient way to fill out a matrix of elements given by function f(i,j) in R?

Tags: arrays, performance, r

I have a function of two scalar values `x_i`, `y_j`.  I have a vector of n `x_i` values, X and n `y_j` values, e.g.

```
myfunction <- function(x,y) min(x,y)
X <- 1:3
Y <- 2:4
```

I want to fill out the $n$ by $n$ matrix whose elements `(i,j)` are given by `myfunction(x_i, y_j)`.  There's a lot of ways to do this in `R`, and I'm curious about their relative performance.

For instance, this seems like a task for `outer`, but it seems to get confused whether it is passing a vector or scalar to `myfunction`.  First consider:

`r
    outer(X, Y, paste)`

gives me each of the pairs

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "1 2" "1 3" "1 4"
[2,] "2 2" "2 3" "2 4"
[3,] "3 2" "3 3" "3 4"
```

Looks good.  But

```
outer(X, Y, myfunction)
```

throws the error:

```
Error: dims [product 9] do not match the length of object [1]
```

Meanwhile other possible functions seem to behave as I expected with scalars, such as:

```
myfunction <- function(x,y) exp((x-y)^2)
```

which works fine

```
outer(X, Y, myfunction)


         [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 2.718282 54.598150 8103.083928
[2,] 1.000000  2.718282   54.598150
[3,] 2.718282  1.000000    2.718282
```

In a few quick numerical experiments, it seems this is slightly faster than `expand.grid`, and the function call more compact, but I don't seem to understand why some functions appear to work as I anticipate and others do not.

The classic `expand.grid` solution also requires the function to work with vector arguments, which means a very different thing for my example with `min`; a different version of the same problem.  Is there a way to enforce the fact that the arguments to my function must be scalars rather than vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to outer must be vectorized,

From the source code

```
   FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
        Y <- rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y)))
        if (length(X)) 
            X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
        robj <- FUN(X, Y, ...)
        dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY)
```

`min` will return a single number, you would want `pmin`.

More generally you could use Vectorize.

Comment: excellent! And thanks for mentioning `Vectorize()` for the general case.  Wonder why `outer` appears to be faster than `expand.grid`, seems like they are doing something very similar?