# Constructing a matrix as function of row and column

Tags: r

The situation is pretty straightforward. I want to create a matrix `A` of n rows and m columns, where the value for each element is given by a predetermined function `f(i, j)`. What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to fill out a matrix of elements given by function f(i,j) in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081611/most-efficient-way-to-fill-out-a-matrix-of-elements-given-by-function-fi-j-in)

Comment: I think I'd leave this one open. They're very closely related, but this one answers this question in a much simpler, more direct way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `outer`:

```
outer(1:3,1:3,function(i,j) i^2+j)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7
[3,]   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided a reproducible example, but you could do something like this:

```
f <- function(i,j) i*j
m <- 4
n <- 2
out <- apply(expand.grid(1:m, 1:n), 1, function(x) f(x[1],x[2]))
dim(out) <- c(m,n)
```